# Applying text to a image (without pushing it)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xhtml

I've been trying to get this worked out but I am completely lost as of now, I've tried many things related to resizing my image at the top of the page and concluded that I could set the background as an extended version of my image & keep the main image to size on it's own using `text-align:center` (since the main image is smaller),

This was working completely fine for me until I realized that in order for me to add buttons I would need to have text on top of that image, but if I try to do this it pushes the image downward, an example of what my site currently would look like is this [my website](http://www.testinghtml.tk), I'm trying to find a way that I can apply text overlay to this main image without disturbing it,

The reason I haven't used `margin-left / margin-right` or `position:absolute` is because it causes the resizing of the main image to not apply properly when I change my browser size. Any help would be greatly appreciated

(My HTML isn't the best seeing as I am still beginning)

```
  <style type="text/css">
 body {
 background-image:url('images/Website Banner Number 2.png');
 background-color:#000000;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="z-index:10">
<div style="text-align:center">
 <img src="images/Website Banner.png" />
</div>
</div>
<div style="z-index:9">
<div style="width:925px" id="container">
 <div id="header" style="background-color:#333333">
  <h3 style="margin-bottom:0;"> <span style="color:#FFFFFF"> &#187;</span><span  
style="color:#0000CC" class="words">[Welcome] </span><span style="color:#FFFFFF"     
  class="words">to Han's tech class site</span> </h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your actual code this makes no sense.

Comment: I figured you might just use "View source" on the webpage I linked, but I'll update with code.

Comment: in order for people to answer your question, you should make it as easy as possible to figure out what's wrong, this means posting the code you think is relevant and other details

Comment: updated with all I could think is relevant from my code to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/JVxmb/).
Is this what you are looking for?

**Background image adjusting according to your window width?**

`background:url("http://www.testinghtml.tk/images/Website Banner Number 2.png") no-repeat scroll center top / cover  transparent;`

Besides suggest you to **add the background to another div** (bodyWrapper) and **not the body** as you may **then adjust the height of the div according to your needs**

Comment: I wish it were xD, I'm trying to keep the layout I already have set, if you haven't already seen it, it's [link](http://www.testinghtml.tk) I'm trying to get some `<a href="url">page</a>` codes within the black tabs you see on the image, so that I can switch pages that way. but whenever I attempt to put these ontop of the image it pushes the image.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using areas on the image as links instead and added the word directly to the image, added this to my code

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
 <img src="images/Website Banner.png" alt="Han's Class" usemap="hans" />
 <map name="hans">
 <area shape="rect" color="#FFFFFF" coords="7,371,90,395" href="index.html" alt="Home">
 <area shape="rect" color="#FFFFFF" coords="117,371,200,395" href="general.html" alt="Information">
 <area shape="rect" color="#FFFFFF" coords="227,373,310,395" href="info.html" alt="General">
 <area shape="rect" color="#FFFFFF" coords="336,373,422,395" href="faq.html" alt="Frequently Asked Questions">
 <area shape="rect" color="#FFFFFF" coords="446,372,532,395" href="rules.html" alt="Rules">
 <area shape="rect" color="#FFFFFF" coords="559,372,645,395" href="forum.html" alt="Forums">
 </map>
</div>
```

I was hoping there was another way I could do this so I could make the buttons light up when I hover over them, but I guess this works as a good alternative, thanks for those who attempted to help though. If you know a better way let me know!